# Retrofit android not working and retrofitError 401

Tags: android, retrofit, domdocument

I am using Retrofit connect electronic devices .but it responding with incorrect data.
Please suggest me some solution to this problem. Do you guys have any idea is it related to connect ?
myUrl :http://11.10.88.23/ajax_control&/

Interface Exapi

```
public interface ExApi {
@GET("/ajax_control&")
public void getFeed(Callback<Document> response);
}
```

Mainclass

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RequestInterceptor{
    Button mButton;
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://11.10.88.23/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestData(BASE_URL);
                    }
            });
    }
    private void requestData(String url){
            RestAdapter adapter=new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(url).build();
            ExApi api=adapter.create(ExApi.class);
            api.getFeed(new Callback<Document>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Document document, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value: " + document.getElementsByTagName("LED").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                            Log.d("lai loi: ", retrofitError.getMessage());
                    }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
            final String author=encodeCredentialsForBasicAuthorization();
            requestFacade.addHeader("Authorization", author);
    }
    private String encodeCredentialsForBasicAuthorization() {
            final String userAndPassword = "user:admin";
            return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userAndPassword.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please suggest me some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Error `401 unauthorized` means request is denied due to invalid credentials. This kind of authentication is called Basic Authentication, and you can pass these parameters in an HTTP header as well.

Here's an article about how that can be done in Retrofit: https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit/

Comment: thanks @Thanh DC, but with Interface "ExApi " .Am i write code it correctly? if wrong .can you help me? sorry i have litte english.

Comment: I think it will easy understand if u use like this :                 @GET("/ajax_control&")
String getFeed();                                                                                            So, when you call this api, it will return json string :                                    ExApi api=adapter.create(ExApi.class);
String responseString =  api.getFeed();

Comment: thanks alot @Thanh DC.I will trying.but myUrl ,it will response Document, not json.so i don't know get it.